# Where are the callback parameters coming from in a recreation of a .map prototype function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm recreating Javascript's *map* function and i'm not understanding *where* these parameters are coming from:

> (this[index], index, this)

I understand what this is the array, i understand this[index] is the value, and index is the number that keeps track of the index on iteration, but where is that all coming from when i'm only passing in:

> x => x * 5

that's the part i'm confused about and havne't found a good explanation about it online.

```
Array.prototype.mymap = function(callback) {
    const resultArray = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
        resultArray.push(callback(this[index], index, this));  // confused about these parameters
    }
    return resultArray;
}

const sample = [1,2,3];    
var output = sample.mymap(x => x * 5);    
console.log(output);
```

Comment: That’s your callback. `x` is the item parameter

Comment: The value of `this` doesn't depend on what you pass as an argument. You're calling `sample.mymap(...)` so `this` is `sample`.

Comment: @Quentin okay I get that but what about "this[index], index, this" why is it in that particular order and HOW is that translating to passing it as a parameter into "x => x * 5"?

Comment: "why is it in that particular order" — Because you're reimplementing `map` and that's what `map` is supposed to pass to the callback.

Comment: @Quentin ah man I don't get it... like I understand what those values mean .. I understand what map does I use it all the time for work but I'm not getting that part.  wish the mod didn't close this question.. thanks for trying

Comment: @user1189352 `this[index]` is passed into the `x` parameter. `index` and `this` are passed into parameters that your callback didn't declare. Also check the other duplicates I added

Comment: It's a normal function call. If you have a function `function foo(a,b,c) {}` and you call it with `foo(1,2,3)` then `a=1, b=2, c=3`. It's much simpler than you might think.

Comment: @Bergi "index and this are passed into parameters that your callback didn't declare" i guess that's the confusing part.... i'll check our the duplicates and see if i can make sense of it. thanks

Comment: @FelixKling i feel like that doesnt' make sense here though.  how is "function callback(x) { return x * 5 }".. how does the "this[index], index, this" translate into that parameter x in that callback?  i asked a senior dev just now and he doesn't know either.. i don't think it's as straight forward as u guys are making this to be

Comment: @user1189352 It works just the same. If you have `function func(x) {}` and call `func(1, 2, 3)` then `x` is `1` and the other two parameters are ignored. If you have an anonymous arrow function `x => x * 5` and you pass `this[index], index, this` to it, then `x` will have the value of `this[index]` and `index` and `this` as second and third parameters will be ignored.

Comment: @Ivar OMG I GET IT.  THANK YOU SO MUCH